# Confusion in lambda expression for a query

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda

i want to execute a query which take the value from the combobox(custIdComboBox) when clicked, finds the name against it in the database and place it in the textbox. i am quite confused making a LAMBDA EXPRESSION for it. although i have tried much but it does not work in a correct or required way.

query: `"select name from customer where custId= " +custIdComboBox.SelectedItem+ ""`

i want the result to be displayed in the textbox(customeName.text).

what i am trying is : `customerName.Text = db.customers.Where(s => s.custId == custIdComboBox.SelectedItem).Select(w => w.name).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have you any compilation errors, or run-time exceptions? Possibly, the reason is that `s.custId` is `int`, but `SelectedItem` is `object`.

Comment: What type is your `SelectedItem`?

Comment: your SelectedItem could be the Customer itself rather than the Id. As pointed above check your SelectedItem type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `SelectedItem` is a `Customer`:

```
var customer = db.customers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.custId == ((Customer)custIdComboBox.SelectedItem).ID);

if (customer != null)
{
     customerName.Text = customer.Name;
}
```

Note if `SelectedItem` may be of a different type, this will throw an `InvalidCastException`

**Edit**

Ok, lets see what the flow of execution is:

1. We're using `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` on your customers collection. This method takes a `Func<T, bool>` and returns **the first match**. So what we need to do is show the method which item we want it to choose
2. We pass the `Func<T, bool>` as a Lambda Expression. Inside the lambda we want to say: *"please find a match for `s.custId` with another object which has the same id (in your case its s.custId)"*
3. In order to do the matching, we use `custIdComboBox.SelectedItem`. The problem with `SelectedItem` is that it is of type `object`, and not of type `Customer` (You can look up ComboBox.SelectedItem on MSDN and see that it returns an `object`). So, we explicitly cast `SelectedItem` to a `Customer`
4. After the cast, we extract the `ID` property of the customer to match it with the `ID` of any object inside the iterated collection
5. `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if it doesn't find a match, so we have to do a `null` check before accessing the `customer` property. If it isn't null, we assign its `Name` property to the `TextBox`

Comment: What would you like me to explain?